# Spring Cloud API Gateway with RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-gateway

Is it possible to post messages to RabbitMQ with the Spring API Gateway? Now, we have the routes configuration in API Gateway which always routes to the particular URI. But, we need to post it in the Queue and wait for the response. Since, API Gateway is reactive we see the over-usage of threads and the application is getting crashed.

Exposed an Rest API inside the Gateway through which the incoming requests are routed and messages are posted in RabbitMQ. But this caused over-usage of threads in Gateway.